# ExtJS 4: Change data in combobox (celleditor)

Tags: javascript, combobox, extjs4, store

I'm using `Ext.form.field.Combobox` as cell editors in grid panel:

```
product: {
    xtype         : "anypartfiltercombobox",
    id            : "product-editor",
    store         : new Ext.data.Store({
        model: "Product",
        data: APP.feedbacks.aUserProducts
    }),
    displayField  : "name",
    valueField    : "id",
    queryMode     : "local",
    emptyText     : "Select game",
    allowBlank    : false,
    forceSelection: true,
    listeners     : {
        select: this._onProductChanged
    }
},
device: {
    xtype         : "anypartfiltercombobox",
    id            : "device-editor",
    store         : Ext.create("stores.Devices", {
        storeId: "device-editor-store",
        data   : APP.feedbacks.aProductDevices
    }),
    displayField  : "name",
    valueField    : "id",
    queryMode     : "local",
    emptyText     : "Select device",
    allowBlank    : false,
    autoRender    : true,
    forceSelection: true
}
```

In `stores.Devices` store I have a method `loadByProduct()` that should be used by changing value in *product* editor.

So source of `this._onProductChanged` is:

```
_onProductChanged = function(oField)
{
    var iProductId = +oField.getValue(),
    oDevicesEditor = Ext.getCmp("device-editor");

    oDevicesEditor.store.loadByProduct(iProductId);
    // Ext.StoresManager.lookUp("device-editor-sore").loadByProduct(iProductId);
}
```

So when I change `product-editor` value first (`device-editor` wasn't activated yet) in `_onProductChanged` I've got *undefined* for `Ext.getCmp("device-editor")`.

But if `device-editor` was already opened, and then I change a product than all works correctly.

Btw, I also tried to get store using `StoresManager` and new data loads but in this case store contains new values and combobox shows old items.

Can anybody help me with solution?

Thanks,
Andrey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Ext.grid.column.Column.getEditor` method instead of finding editor by id. This method should create editor if it is not created yet.

Comment: Thank you a lot!! I spent a lot of time looking for this, and each time when I looked at `Ext.grid.column.Column` APIs page I missed this method.